# jquery find out whether user is typing or not

Tags: jquery

My web page need some hotkeys, just single hotkey. So I need to find out whether user is typing or not to apply hotkeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event on the document's body

```
$(document.body).keypress(function(event){
  //do your stuff (event.keyCode tells you what's been pressed)
});
```

[You can also consider using the jQuery plug-in for hotkeys.](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/YC7Ef/)? (it does an alert when you press the TAB key and the focus is anywhere on the page)

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) //TAB key
    {
        alert('this is the tab key!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(window).keypress(function(e){ //alternatively look up the keydown and keyup functions
    switch (e.which)
    {
      case 13: //whatever key code you want to check for
      {
        //do stuff
      } return false; //prevent propagation of keypress event
      default:
      {
        //log the keycode to console so you can figure out which key is which
        //there are a number of tables of keycodes available online.
        if (window.console) console.log(e.which);
      } break;
    }
  });
});
```

Please do not destroy your user experience: use your powers for good or for awesome.